# How to add the label box value in vb6

Tags: vb6

I want to add the lable box value in vb6

```
Label1 = 200
Label2 = 500
```

'Adding

```
Label3 = Label1 + Label2
```

'Showing output as

```
Label3 = 200500
```

I want add the 2 values

Expected Output

```
Label3 = 700
```

What was the problem in my code

Need code help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two answers are correct, but neither of it explain to you why this happens. VB 6 (or 5 or 4 or 3) has a default property for the controls. In the case of the label, the default property is caption. Since caption is a string, and string can be concatenate using & or +, VB pickup the type and then it does the math (in this case, concat).

```
Label3= val(Label1) + val(Label2)
```

This works good.. Also you can use Cint or any other convert to number function.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but you should be using `.Caption` instead of relying on the default property.

Comment: @JP. I didn't want to pass through the other answers, that are good, but not explained ;)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use UI controls to hold values, they should only be used for display or interaction with the user. If you need to store a few numbers, use (correctly typed) variables.

Answer (score 2):

long time haven't worked with VB6 but try

```
Label3.caption = val(Label1.caption) + val(Label2.caption)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:-

```
textbox3.text = val(textbox1.text) + val(textbox2.text)
```